# Deploy war file fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, war

I am working on a system with two servers. When updating a site i deploy a war file to each server. It worked on one but on the other when i go through the process the war file creates the ROOT folder but its owner and group is root whereas on the other server owner was tomcat.

I changed ownership and group back but when i go to load the site it doesnt load. Looked through the ROOT folder and noticed the WEB-INF/public folder which contains the site content wasnt created. Does anyone have any idea why this would be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the user in which tomcat is started and who owns the process on each server.

Comment: Thanks. Its a strange one. Do this process all the time but sometimes it performs unexpectedly. Usually i would have ROOT.war and ROOT folder. I ftp new ROOT.war file but call it ROOT.new. I delete old ROOT.war, wait for a while and the ROOT folder automatically gets removed. I then rename the ROOT.new ROOT.war and it creates a new ROOT folder. That is the expected behavior but on other occasions it has changed group and owner as well as the ROOT folder not being generated.

Comment: In IT the statement "This is strange" is more frequent than people expect haha :')

Comment: Strangely you're right :). Since last we spoke the sites are all back up. Nothing i did. Think the changes just needed to take effect. Only concern is that considering ROOT folders generally got wiped when ROOT.war file was deleted it hasnt happened on one site and seeing as there seems to be a delay i'm expecting it to wipe itself tonight. Fingers crossed i'm wrong but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: It shouldn't do but as a precautionary measure, I would take a back up of all the important things anyway and put them somewhere else.